# Heroku SSL with Route53

Tags: heroku, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My SSL certificate is all set up and ready to go on Heroku. I followed the instructions here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/route-53 to correctly redirect requests (e.g. example.com to www.example.com) using AWS S3. HTTPS works great when requestiong https://www.example.com; however, if I attempt to request https://example.com, the page cannot be found. Any thoughts?

Comment: The redirect setup documented there will only work for "http"://example.com... not https.  Does it work without the "s" in "https?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Route 53, you want to create the following DNS records:

- www.example.com `CNAME` your_app.herokuapp.com
- example.com `ALIAS` your_app.herokuapp.com

Your `www.example.com` hostname should be a `CNAME` record that delegates to your Heroku App hostname.  Any other regular hostnames should be `CNAME`s.

The `example.com` "Apex" or "naked domain" record must return an `A` record and cannot be a `CNAME`.  Route53 implements the `ALIAS` record type, which looks up the values for `your_app.herokuapp.com` and returns a set of current `A` records to match.

Comment: Apparently Route53 restricts ALIAS record types to their network. That being said, my attempt did not work. I moved over to https://dnsimple.com/r/4111a5ad69d1f2

Comment: I am having the same problem, so there is nothing else that can be done but switch to DNSimple?

Comment: DNSimple definitely works.  We are using it for Heroku ourselves.  I believe Route53 should also work, despite comments above.

Comment: Hi @Winfield . How should the ALIAS record be defined for the naked domain? I've tried using an s3 bucket to preform a static redirect to www.example.com but i'm still having problem with https:///example.com. Can you specify the required settings? Thanks!

Comment: @UriKlar - Just as it says above.  You can setup an ALIAS from yourcompany.com => your_app.herokuapp.com

Comment: This does not work as described. Route 53 only allows creating alias records for amazon resources, or to other records in the hosted zone. It will not resolve a name at lookup time like most other alias implementations.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. You can't create an alias record to heroku on route 53. So I guess I am going to switch to another provider.

Comment: Absolutely ridiculous that you cant do this on AWS Route53 its so frustrating.

Answer (score -1):

I've just been through this myself. The easiest and cheapest way to do it is to let Heroku (minimum 7 USD box) manage the SSL (ACM).

Add a custom domain there and enable SSL and you will be presented with a DNS target like:  www.yourcustomdomain.com.herokudns.com. In Route53 add a CNAME record for your www.yourcustomdomain.com with the target into www.yourcustomdomain.com.herokudns.com.

Wait to refresh the DNS internationally.

I would assume the S3 bucket for directing the naked domain into the www.domain was done previous to the above mentioned.

Comment: I think you missed the point so I’d assume my English is poor ... I pretty much said: “let Heroku manage the SSL (ACM)” exactly because S3 bucket redirect cannot handle it. S3 part is for directing xxx.com into www.xxx.com.