# Wildcard CNAME and Wildcard MX Record

Tags: heroku, amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

We are in the process of migrating from Engine Yard to Heorku. The struggle is with the Heroku's use of CNAME records.

I would like to setup the following records on Route53 (switching away to another DNS provider is a last resort, I would prefer to keep things on AWS as we have a lot of other services we use there).

```
CNAME www.example.com corporate-site.wpengine.com
CNAME *.example.com   example.herokuapp.com
MX    *.example.com   1 mailgun.org
MX      example.com   1 aspmx.l.google.com
```

The idea is that someone can go to `demo.example.com` and get served the heroku application. They can also email `support@example.com` and this will go to a normal gmail inbox. But when they send an email to `post@demo.example.com` the email is processed by MailGun. For example, `Craiglist` uses this approach to reply to posts.

The DNS setup above is not valid for Route53. That's because CNAME records names must be unique across all record types. This is not a problem however with A records, which is the way it was setup before.

Note that a simple `301` redirect would not do here. We want `demo.example.com` to always point to `demo.example.com`. Each subdomain is used by the heroku application to determine the account to load (or if you think of the Craiglist example, a seperate geographic region, we don't want to redirect to just one region and have many regions we create dynamically).

What is the recommended way to solve this problem?

Comment: After some more digging I found that Route53 supports Alias records, but not outside of their own network. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295614/heroku-ssl-with-route53. Still wondering if there is a solution to this that doesn't involve switching.

Comment: Even if you find a provider that allows you to have this configuration, you need to know that it is fundamentally inconsistent with the way DNS is supposed to work.  A CNAME, by definition, means there should be not other records for particular host.  The correct MX record, for someone trying to email you to use, is the MX record of the *target* of the CNAME (that is, the MX of the host where the CNAME record is pointing to)... which is not what you want. In reality, implementations vary, though, so email deliverability may vary by sender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking to Heroku support, Mailgun support and many of you. It became apparent this could not be done with Route53.

To achieve this you need to either use an `ALIAS` record or an `ANAME` record. `Route53` supports aliasing only to endpoints inside your own AWS account. Therefore, it is not doable with their service as of yet.

We switched to `DNSMadeEasy` which was recommended by Heroku and have very good performance. I find the interface very unintuitive, but you only need to do it once. All I needed to do was create a wildcard `ANAME` record pointing to heroku and everything else worked fine.

I do recommend you checkout `DNSimple`, their interface is great and I love their service. They are not as established as DNSMadeSimple, but they are certainly more friendly to use. I hope to one day use their service.

Comment: Mauilgun does not support adding a wildcard domain anyway, so that would be a dead end.

Answer (score 2):

> I found that Route53 supports Alias records, but not outside of their own network

The workaround is here:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/route-53#naked-root-domain

Basically:

1. Create an S3 bucket called: `yourdomain.com` and make it redirect to `www.yourdomain.com`
2. On Route 53, create an `A` record alias to point to your bucket for the `Naked/root` domain of `yourdomain.com`
3. Finally, create a CNAME record for `www.yourdomain.com` to point to `yourapp.herokuapp.com`

That should do it.

Comment: But that gives me a 301 redirect to `www` which is not what I want to do. I want to stay at `demo.example.com` and do redirection at the DNS level. Maybe I did not stress that part well enough in the question, I will update it.

Comment: Then there's nothing you can do with Route 53. Use another one of the services that Heroku recommends.

Comment: Thanks Rico, that was my conclusion as well. I will try one of the other services tomorrow and come back with an answer. Heroku Support recommended using `DNSMadeEasy` so will be trying that.